# How to change name of legend item in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: layout, legend, arcgis, layer

In ArcGIS Pro, I have a legend in a layout attached to a map.  In the Contents pane I see the Layer Name as it appears on the Layout.  However, I am unable to change the name of the Layer.

On so many other elements in the Contents pane one can left click the item name, turning the name of the item to editable.  However on Legend elements this is not available.  I can right click the item (to see 'set as default', 'Remove', and 'Properties'.  In properties there is ever opportunity to change anything about the element (formatting, size, font, a gallery of possible styles , grouping, layer name, group name, labels, description, etc. ), however I see no place to change the visible text that appears in the legend.  Otherwise, the Legend is unlcoked, it is in a series of groups.  Alternatively, in the map that the legend elements are attached to I see the Layer and its properties; in the General tab, I can change that Layer name (in the map), but this does not change the Layout.  When I select the Layer in Contents, the tab/button bar/strip at top highlights the Feature Layer, but I see no way to change how it is Named in the Layout.

I suspect that this is an easy fix, but for the life of me I can't find where Pro has hidden this functionality.  Thank you.

Comment: Please post your codes here.

Answer (score 0):

This ended up being an issue of Grouped elements.
When I UnGrouped the elements I was eventually able to edit the values.